# $A$ relatively weakly compact then $\overline{\text{aco}} (A)$ is relatively weakly compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, weak-topology

Let $(X,\|.\|) $ be a separable Banach space.

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$, the absolutely convex hull of the set $A$ is :
$$
\text{aco}(A)=\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}x_{i}:x_{i}\in A, \lambda_{i}\in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\lambda_{i}|\leq 1\}
$$

> ***Theorem.*** *("**Krein's theorem**")*
>
> $A$ be a weakly compact subset of X. Then $\overline{\text{aco}} (A)$ the closure of $\text{aco(A)}$ is weakly compact.

Show that :

$A$ relatively weakly compact then $\overline{\text{aco}} (A)$ is  relatively weakly compact.

Comment: If you want to see how this follows from Krein’s just note that acot$(A)\subset \text{acot}(\overline{A})$ so by taking weak closure on both sides we see that $\overline{\text{acot}(A)}$ is contained in a weakly compact set. Since it is closed it is then itself weakly compact.

Comment: if $C\subset k$ and $C$ weakly closed and $K$ is weakly compact then $C$ is weakly compact ?

Comment: Yes; this holds in all topologies

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*
I suppose ["relatively compact"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subspace) means "closure is compact".  I use overbar for weak closure.

Suppose $A$ is relatively weakly compact.  Then $\overline{A}$ is weakly compact.  So by Krein, $\overline{\text{aco}(\overline{A})}$ is weakly compact. Is it true that 
$\overline{\text{aco}({A})}=\overline{\text{aco}(\overline{A})}$ ?

Comment: I understood this. My problem is to show that : $$\overline{\text{aco}}(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{\text{aco}}({A}) $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the map $\mathbb{C}\times X \rightarrow X$, $(\alpha, x)\mapsto \alpha x$ is continuous if $X$ is endowed with the weak topology. Hence the set $A'=[-1,1]A$ is weakly compact since it is the image of $[-1,1]\times A$ under this map. Now we claim that $\text{acot}(A)=\text{conv}(A')$. Indeed, if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i\in \text{acot}(A)$ with $0<\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|\leq 1$ and $x_i\in A$ we can rewrite $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i$ as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{|\lambda_i|}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n|\lambda_j|}(\text{sign}(\lambda_i)\sum\limits_{j=1}^n|\lambda_j|)$ to see that it in fact lies in $\text{conv}(A')$. Conversely, it is easy to see that $\text{conv}(A')\subseteq \text{acot}(A)$ (and actually not needed for this result). Now, the Eberlin-Smulian theorem states that $\text{conv}(A')$ is weakly precompact, i.e. $\text{acot}(A)$is weakly precompact.